# SIGSEGV error on online judges

Tags: c++, recursion, combinations, segmentation-fault

the following code gives the combination of two numbers (nCr) through recursive calling and is the solution to the following problem:

Rohit dreams he is in a shop with an infinite amount of marbles. He is allowed to select n marbles. There are marbles of k different colors. From each color there are also infinitely many marbles. Rohit wants to have at least one marble of each color, but still there are a lot of possibilities for his selection. In his effort to make a decision he wakes up.
Now he asks you how many possibilities for his selection he would have had.
Assume that marbles of equal color can't be distinguished, and the order of the marbles is irrelevant.
Input

The first line of input contains a number T <= 100 that indicates the number of test cases to follow. Each test case consists of one line containing n and k, where n is the number of marbles Rohit selects and k is the number of different colors of the marbles. You can assume that 1<=k<=n<=1000000.
Output

For each test case print the number of possibilities that Rohit would have had.
You can assume that this number fits into a signed 64 bit integer.
Example

Input:
2
10 10
30 7

Output:
1
475020

and here is the my solution for the problem:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

long long int C(int n,int r)
{
    if(r==1)
        return n;
    if(n==r)
        return 1;
    long long int c=C(n-1,r)+C(n-1,r-1);
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n,r;
        cin>>n>>r;
        cout<<C(n-1,r-1)<<endl;
    }
}
```

My problem is on my gcc compiler CodeBlocks the code is running smoothly without any error and is giving the write answer, but the online judge is giving me a runtime error: SIGSEGV.
I searched about the error and it is related to the use of excess memory by the program but still i cannot find the error in my code.
So please tell me can my code be modified to fit the conditions of the question or do i have to think from a new perspective?

Comment: My guess is that the online judge probably gives your `main` an input that makes it overflow the stack.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight please tell me how to get rid of that overflow

Comment: @InsaynAsasin it would seem the point to the content you wish to compete in is to be able to come up with a function to solve this problem _non-recursively_... this is different from a contest whose point is to be able to ask for others to rewrite recursive code for you, no?

Comment: @mah i dont know what you said but i think when i said "So please tell me can my code be modified to fit the conditions of the question or do i have to think from a new perspective?" i meant that if my code can be corrected then how is it possible or else whether i need a new and efficient program
...

Comment: @mah you didn't do any of the above two. dasblinkenlight told that it is because of stack overflow but he didn't tell me whether my code can be modified or i need to change the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if r == 1, and n is bigger that r. when the function is called at the first time, the local variable r will be 0, so for the recursion C(n-1,r-1), r will never be 1, and n will never equal to r.  so the recursion C(n-1,r-1) can't end. And it will stack overflow.

Comment: according the question the answer will be of the form nCr and i think the range of n and r are 0<r<=n

Answer (score 0):

Your problem contains stack overflow). Function calls allocate memory on stack (small (around 1-10MB) chunk of preallocated memory) to save some data to be able to return to an initial location after the call. Recursive functions are very dangerous because there may be very large amount of nested call that require a lot of allocations on the stack, leading to its overflow and eventually, segfault. In your case consider that input contains two numbers - 1000000000 and  1000000001. The answer will be 1000000001 but your implementation will make at least 1000000000 nested calls. That is more than enough to cause stack overflow.

Comment: then i guess i will have to think of another way that will not use recursion because it is given that the input is of the order 10^6